# Batch File Move Not Working For Some Special Characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, symbols, move, windows-scripting

I have a video hosting website with videos stored in year-month-day subfolders. I have a 2nd folder which has all the thumbnails for all the videos in the first folder.

The script below recursively gets the name and directory of a video file in the first folder and uses those variables to move the thumbnail in the second folder to the third folder.

```
@echo on

Set first_folder="G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
Set second_folder="C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs unorganized"
Set third_folder="C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs organized"

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d %first_folder%') do (

for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /b /a:d %first_folder%\%%A') do (

    for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('dir /b /a:d %first_folder%\%%A\%%B') do (

        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

        for /f "delims= eol=" %%D in ('dir %first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C /b') do (

            for /f "delims=\ tokens=7-9" %%f in ("%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C\%%D") do (

                    IF EXIST %third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h (

                        move %second_folder%\"%%~nD.jpg" %third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h\"%%~nD.jpg"

                    )
            )
        )
    )  
) 
)

@echo on

echo "image files have been translated successfully!"
pause
```

Only problem is if the video name has special characters like exclamation points and parenthesis sometimes for a weird reason, the script says:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Example: A thumbnail for a video named **The King and the Frog!!.mp4** will give the error but a thumbnail for **The King and the Frog.mp4** will move!

Any ideas on why they won't move?

Another thing is when the script reaches a subfolder with a name like **14th & 15th** it won't pick it up in the directory.

Updated Working Code:

```
@echo on

Set "first_folder=G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
Set "second_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs unorganized"
Set "third_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs organized"

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%"') do (
 for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%\%%A"') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B"') do (
    for /f "delims= eol=" %%D in ('dir "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C" /b') do (
      for /f "delims=\ tokens=7-9" %%f in ("%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C\%%D") do (
                IF EXIST "%third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h" (
                    move "%second_folder%\%%~nD.jpg" "%third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h\%%~nD.jpg"
          )
       )
    )
 )  
) 
)

@echo on

echo "image files have been translated successfully!"
pause
```

Comment: I suspect it's because the `!` is a special character used in delayed expansion, but haven't got time to investigate fully. By the way, it's unusual to put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` inside a loop. It's usually at the top of a batch file. Its scope is the entire batch file (or a subroutine that you `call`) regardless of whether it's enclosed in a statement block. In other words, it doesn't respect lexical scope.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `delayedexpansion` when you do not use it?

Comment: I deleted the delayed expansion part and that fixed the issue with exclamation points! Now the only issue I have left is the script skipping folders with names like "14th & 15th"

Comment: Then fix your variable `set "var=path"` see the double quote positions. and then use it like `move "%second_folder%\%%~nD.jpg"`

Comment: The `&` character is a statement separator and therefore needs to be inside quotes like Gerhard said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting variable paths, you need to enclose the entire variable and value in double quotes:

```
Set "first_folder=G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
Set "second_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs unorganized"
Set "third_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs organized"
```

Then use them as:

```
move "%second_folder%\%%~nD.jpg" "%third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h\%%~nD.jpg"
```

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` should be removed in the script as you never use it, yet it will utilize the `!`  hence your issue.

To understand the quoting problem have a look at your `set` variables and your for loop, as in this example:

you have double quotes in path here, double quotes now forms part of the value:

```
set first_folder="G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
```

then in the loop:

```
for...("%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C\%%D")
```

which translates to:

```
"%first_folder%"\somedir\14th & 15th
```

So your current code (Not enhanced by me) just fixing problems:

```
@echo on

Set "first_folder=G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
Set "second_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs unorganized"
Set "third_folder="C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs organized"

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%"') do (
 for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%\%%A"') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('dir /b /a:d "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B"') do (
    for /f "delims= eol=" %%D in ('dir /b "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C"') do (
      for /f "delims=\ tokens=7-9" %%f in ("%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C\%%D") do (
                    IF EXIST "%third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h" (
                        move "%second_folder%\%%~nD.jpg" "%third_folder%\%%f-%%g-%%h\%%~nD.jpg"
              )
           )
        )
     )  
   ) 
)

@echo on

echo "image files have been translated successfully!"
pause
```

Comment: Here I get "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: It is not picking up the filename and is searching for a file named "%~nD.jpg"

Comment: but what did you change? I cannot see what you changed.

Comment: See the edited version of your code in my edit. I will be removing the code soon as I am not re-writing it to be as it should, so use it now and let me know please.

Comment: I edited and added a screenshot so you can see the error I get

Comment: but I already posted a corrected version, did you try it? Your error screenshot clearly shows an additional double quote in the if statement, which I do not have in my version.

Comment: Yes I just didn't update the code in the post. I just updated with the code I am using now

Comment: But I do not have the extra double quote as per your screenshot.. please try again. Copy as is. No changes.

Comment: Oh I see, I apologize. Didn't see the error. Thank you for this! The code works

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've re-written this to remove some redundancy and use some better practices.

This should do the needful as you expect sorry it took a few as I am getting ready in AM.

I changed the script to create the expected folder if it does not exist to move to and I have the script to check ot make sure the source jpeg exists which it may not, and it will aert you if it doesn't instead of throwing an error for the move.

I also have the MOVE file over-rite existing files instead of prompting.

```
@(setlocal
  echo on
)

Set "first_folder=G:\Site Backups\BM Backup\public_html\Videos\hold"
Set "second_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs unorganized"
Set "third_folder=C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\thumbs organized"

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('
  dir /b /ad "%first_folder%"') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('
    dir /b /ad "%first_folder%\%%A"') do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('
      dir /b /ad "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B"') do (
      for %%_ IN (
        "%first_folder%\%%A\%%B\%%C\*") do (
        IF NOT EXIST "%third_folder%\%%A-%%B-%%C" (
          MD "%third_folder%\%%A-%%B-%%C" )
        IF EXIST "%second_folder%\%%~n_.jpg" (
          MOVE /Y "%second_folder%\%%~n_.jpg" "%third_folder%\%%A-%%B-%%C\%%~n_.jpg"
        ) ELSE (
          ECHO. The File "%second_folder%\%%~n_.jpg" DOES NOT EXIST!
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

@echo off

echo "image files have been translated successfully!"
pause
```

Using `Setlocal` inside your loop is going to cause unneeded memory bloat in your script, and then run out of clonable memory spaces which can throw errors because you don't; use a paired `endlocal` in the same block; it's also completely unnecessary as it provides no purpose in your code.

`Enabledelayedexpansion` is causing you the error with the. Exclamation marks etc.and is not needed for your code in any way.

Further your script is unnecessarily re-casting the values of the names of the subfolders as new loop variables that can be discarded.

Fourth your quoting on the `SET` and `MOVE` commands is going to cause you problems.

I'll re-write this in a few minutes to remove some of the redundancies and fix those bits to better practice.

However to explain the needful, you should wrap the entire directory tree and file name in quotes, not just the filenames for the `move` commands, and your directory names that you `set` early on all have quotes surrounding them in their variables which is nor generally a positive thing.

Setting variables this way can end up with whitespace trailing them its good practice to use `set "variable=value here without any unnecessary quotes "necessary quotes are okay though, so long as they are in pairs " and this is still in the variable"` as trailing whitespace is not possible.

Comment: @WizardKhalifard Glad to help! :)